# Taking photos within and iOS app, without appearing within the iOS Photos app

Tags: ios, photos

I am developing an app in which the capability of adding photos & videos is added. However, I want the photos & videos to be only viewable within the application itself and not also in the iOS standard Photos app. Does anyone know if there is a way of limiting the cameras saving path?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

When you take photos within your app, they don't automatically show up in the Camera Roll. This is the default (i.e. if you *want* them to show up in Camera Roll, you have to do something special).